# according to SMART hard disk is not broken, but I have errors in dmesg

Tags: hard-disk, smart

Sometimes I have strange troubles booting my computer (which runs Debian). So I issued "dmesg" command. In its output I saw a lot of errors. However, when I run extended SMART test on hard disks (using "smartctl -t long /dev/sda" command), the result is that my disks are not broken.

What can be the reason of those errors?

Here are the errors:

```
   (...)
      [  505.918537] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x400 SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
      [  505.918549] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
      [  505.918558] ata3: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
      [  505.918566] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [  505.918579] ata3.00: cmd 60/40:50:20:5b:60/00:00:0b:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq 32768 in
               res 40/00:54:20:5b:60/00:00:0b:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [  505.918586] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [  505.918595] ata3: hard resetting link
      [  506.410055] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
      [  506.422648] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
      [  506.422679] ata3: EH complete
      [ 1633.123880] md: bind<sdb3>
      [ 1633.187966] RAID1 conf printout:
      [ 1633.187977]  --- wd:1 rd:2
      [ 1633.187984]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:sda3
      [ 1633.187989]  disk 1, wo:1, o:1, dev:sdb3
      [ 1633.188866] md: recovery of RAID array md0
      [ 1633.188871] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
      [ 1633.188875] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for recovery.
      [ 1633.188890] md: using 128k window, over a total of 1943618560k.
      [ 1634.167341] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x7f80 SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
      [ 1634.167353] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
      [ 1634.167361] ata3: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
      [ 1634.167369] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1634.167382] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:38:00:00:6f/02:00:01:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:6c:00:0c:6f/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1634.167389] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1634.167395] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1634.167407] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:40:00:02:6f/02:00:01:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:6c:00:0c:6f/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1634.167413] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1634.167418] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1634.167429] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:48:00:04:6f/02:00:01:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:6c:00:0c:6f/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1634.167435] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1634.167439] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1634.167451] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:50:00:06:6f/02:00:01:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:6c:00:0c:6f/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1634.167457] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1634.167462] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1634.167473] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:58:00:08:6f/02:00:01:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:6c:00:0c:6f/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1634.167479] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1634.167484] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1634.167495] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:60:00:0a:6f/02:00:01:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:6c:00:0c:6f/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1634.167500] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1634.167505] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1634.167516] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:68:00:0c:6f/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq 65536 in
               res 40/00:6c:00:0c:6f/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1634.167522] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1634.167527] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1634.167538] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:70:80:0c:6f/02:00:01:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:6c:00:0c:6f/00:00:01:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1634.167544] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1634.167553] ata3: hard resetting link
      [ 1634.658816] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
      [ 1634.672645] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
      [ 1634.672696] ata3: EH complete
      [ 1637.687898] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x3ff000 SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
      [ 1637.687910] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
      [ 1637.687918] ata3: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
      [ 1637.687926] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1637.687940] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:60:80:a7:af/02:00:02:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:ac:00:b4:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1637.687947] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1637.687953] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1637.687965] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:68:80:a9:af/02:00:02:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:ac:00:b4:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1637.687971] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1637.687976] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1637.687987] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:70:80:ab:af/01:00:02:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq 196608 in
               res 40/00:ac:00:b4:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1637.687993] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1637.687998] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1637.688009] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:78:00:ad:af/02:00:02:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:ac:00:b4:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1637.688015] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1637.688020] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1637.688031] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:80:00:af:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq 65536 in
               res 40/00:ac:00:b4:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1637.688037] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1637.688042] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1637.688053] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:88:80:af:af/01:00:02:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq 131072 in
               res 40/00:ac:00:b4:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1637.688059] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1637.688064] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1637.688075] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:90:80:b0:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq 65536 in
               res 40/00:ac:00:b4:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1637.688081] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1637.688085] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1637.688096] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:98:00:b1:af/02:00:02:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:ac:00:b4:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1637.688102] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1637.688107] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1637.688118] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:a0:00:b3:af/01:00:02:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq 131072 in
               res 40/00:ac:00:b4:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1637.688124] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1637.688129] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1637.688140] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:a8:00:b4:af/01:00:02:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq 131072 in
               res 40/00:ac:00:b4:af/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1637.688146] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1637.688154] ata3: hard resetting link
      [ 1638.179398] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
      [ 1638.192977] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
      [ 1638.193029] ata3: EH complete
      [ 1640.259492] md: export_rdev(sdb1)
      [ 1640.326109] md: bind<sdb1>
      [ 1640.346712] RAID1 conf printout:
      [ 1640.346724]  --- wd:1 rd:2
      [ 1640.346731]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:sda1
      [ 1640.346736]  disk 1, wo:1, o:1, dev:sdb1
      [ 1640.346893] md: delaying recovery of md1 until md0 has finished (they share one or more physical units)
      [ 1657.987964] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x40000 SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
      [ 1657.987975] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
      [ 1657.987984] ata3: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
      [ 1657.987992] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1657.988006] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:90:00:30:2e/03:00:09:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq 393216 in
               res 40/00:94:00:30:2e/00:00:09:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1657.988013] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1657.988022] ata3: hard resetting link
      [ 1658.479548] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
      [ 1658.493107] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
      [ 1658.493147] ata3: EH complete
      [ 1670.547791] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
      [ 1670.547805] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x7f SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
      [ 1670.547812] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
      [ 1670.547820] ata3: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
      [ 1670.547826] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1670.547839] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:00:00:1f:2e/01:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 196608 in
               res 40/00:2c:00:26:2e/00:00:0c:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1670.547846] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1670.547852] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1670.547863] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:08:80:20:2e/00:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 65536 in
               res 40/00:2c:00:26:2e/00:00:0c:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1670.547869] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1670.547875] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1670.547886] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:10:00:21:2e/02:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:2c:00:26:2e/00:00:0c:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1670.547892] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1670.547896] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1670.547907] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:18:00:23:2e/02:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:2c:00:26:2e/00:00:0c:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1670.547913] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1670.547918] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1670.547929] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:20:00:25:2e/01:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq 131072 in
               res 40/00:2c:00:26:2e/00:00:0c:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1670.547935] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1670.547940] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1670.547951] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:28:00:26:2e/02:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:2c:00:26:2e/00:00:0c:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1670.547957] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1670.547961] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
      [ 1670.547972] ata3.00: cmd 60/00:30:00:28:2e/02:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq 262144 in
               res 40/00:2c:00:26:2e/00:00:0c:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
      [ 1670.547978] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
      [ 1670.547987] ata3: hard resetting link
      [ 1671.039264] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
      [ 1671.053386] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
      [ 1671.053444] ata3: EH complete
      [ 2422.512002] md: md0: recovery done.
      [ 2422.547344] md: recovery of RAID array md1
      [ 2422.547355] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
      [ 2422.547360] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for recovery.
      [ 2422.547378] md: using 128k window, over a total of 4877312k.
      [ 2422.668465] RAID1 conf printout:
      [ 2422.668474]  --- wd:2 rd:2
      [ 2422.668480]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:sda3
      [ 2422.668486]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:sdb3
      [ 2469.990451] md: md1: recovery done.
      [ 2470.049986] RAID1 conf printout:
      [ 2470.049997]  --- wd:2 rd:2
      [ 2470.050003]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:sda1
      [ 2470.050009]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:sdb1
      [ 3304.445149] PM: Hibernation mode set to 'platform'
      [ 3304.782375] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
      [ 3307.028591] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
      (...)
```

Comment: This could be related to a bad SATA or power cable, or maybe a bad power supply.

Comment: I've also seen it with bad controllers that freeze and need resetting.

Comment: I added an answer to this question that included similar but not identical dmesg output eg (sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device and EXT4-fs warning) I feel these would have helped people googling for the problem. The answer was deleted even though it did not match any of the reasons stated on https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers. I had the issue on a SSD mounted at /home. I tried disconnecting and reconnecting the power and SATA cable but the error persisted. Luckily I had a spare SATA cable. After replacing the SATA cable I had no errors and the issue has not reoccured.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, keep in mind that **SMART saying that your drive is healthy doesn't necessarily mean that the drive *is* healthy.** SMART reports are an *aid*, not an absolute truth.

If all you are interested in is what to do, rather than why, then feel free to scroll down to the last few paragraphs; however, the interim text will tell you why I think what I propose is the correct course of action, and how to derive that from what you posted.

With that said, let's look at what one of those errors are telling us.

```
[ 1670.547805] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x7f SErr 0x280900 action 0x6 frozen
[ 1670.547812] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[ 1670.547820] ata3: SError: { UnrecovData HostInt 10B8B BadCRC }
[ 1670.547826] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1670.547839] ata3.00: cmd 60/80:00:00:1f:2e/01:00:0c:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 196608 in
           res 40/00:2c:00:26:2e/00:00:0c:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 1670.547846] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1670.547852] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

(I hope I got the parts that should go together, but you were getting a bundle of those so it should be okay either way.)

The [Linux ata Wiki has a page explaining how to read these errors](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Libata_error_messages). Particularly,

- A `status` value of `DRDY` means "Device ready. Normally 1, when all is OK." Seeing a status value of `DRDY` is perfectly normal and expected.
- `SError` has multiple component values, of which you are seeing (in this particular snippet):

  - `UnrecovData` "Data integrity error occurred, interface did not recover"
  - `HostInt` "Host bus adapter internal error"
  - `10B8B` "10b to 8b decoding error occurred"
  - `BadCRC` "Link layer CRC error occurred"

10b8b coding, which encodes 8 bits as 10 bits to aid with both signal synchronization and error detection, is used on the physical cabling, not necessarily on the drive itself. The drive most likely uses other forms of FEC or ECC coding, and an error there would normally show up as some form of I/O error, likely with an `error` value of `UNC` ("uncorrectable error - often due to bad sectors on the disk"), likely with "media error" ("software detected a media error") in parenthesis at the end of the `res` line. This latter is not what you are seeing, so while we can't completely rule it out, it seems unlikely.

The "link layer" is the physical cables and circuit board traces between the drive's own controller, and the disk drive interface chip (likely part of the [southbridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_%28computing%29) on your computer's motherboard, but could be located at an offboard HBA).

A host bus adapter, also known as a HBA, is the circuitry that connects to storage equipment. Also colloquially known as a "disk controller", a term which is a bit of a misnomer with modern systems. The most visible part of the HBA is generally the connection ports, most often these days either SATA or some SAS form factor.

The `UnrecovData` and `HostInt` flags basically tell us that "something just went horribly wrong, and there was no way to recover or no attempt at recovery was made". The opposite would likely be `RecovData`, which indicates that a "data integrity error occurred, but the interface recovered". (As an aside, I probably would have used `HBAInt` instead of `HostInt`, as the "host" refers to the HBA, not the whole system.)

The combination of `10B8B` and `BadCRC`, which both point to the physical link layer, makes me suspect a cabling issue.

This suspicion is also supported by the fact that the SMART self-tests, which are completely internal to the drive except for status reporting, are finding no errors that the manufacturer feels are serious enough to warrant reporting in the results. If the drive was having problems storing or reading data, the long SMART self-test in particular should have reported that.

## TL;DR:

The first thing I would do is thus simply to **unplug and re-plug the SATA cable at both ends;** it may be slightly loose, causing it to lose electrical contact intermittently. See if that resolves the problem. It might even be worth doing this to all SATA cabling in your computer, not just the affected disk. If you are using an off-board HBA, I would also remove and re-seat that card, mainly because it's an easy thing to try while you are already messing around with the cabling.

Failing that, **try throwing away and replacing the SATA cable, preferably with a high-quality cable.** A high-quality cable will be slightly more expensive, but I find that it's usually well worth the small extra expense if it helps avoid headaches like this. Nobody likes seeing their storage spewing errors!

Comment: I unplughed and re-plugged the SATA cable and it solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user983447 Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I noticed that I had plugged two disks on two different disk controllers: The first one was PCI-Express and the second normal PCI. I got rid of the BadCRC error when I plugged the both RAID disks on the same controller.

Comment: So when that controller dies, it takes both disks with it?

Comment: Yes, but it's much more likely that the disk dies than the controller. Also, it would be a better idea to NOT use the PCI-controller, but a high speed PCI-Express -controller.